# Proving a Function Converges

Tags: real-analysis

I am a little confused on the following proof, mostly because it is decreasing and I haven't handled decreasing functions much.

if $x_1=12, x_n=\frac{3}{4}x_{n-1} +2$; Prove $x_n$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that $y_n=x_n-8$ is a convergent series. $$y_n+8=\frac{3}{4}(y_{n-1}+8)+2\\y_n=\frac{3}{4}y_{n-1}$$
You've started from $y_1=4$, $y_n$ is monotonically decreasing, and it is bound on the lower side by $0$. Therefore $y_n$ is convergent, and so is $x_n$.

How did I get $8$?. Well, I assumed that the limit exists, and called it L. Then $L=\frac{3}{4}L+2$ yields $L=8$

Answer (score 1):

If $x_{n+1} = \frac 3 4 x_n +2$ then $x_{n+1}-x_n = 2 - \frac 1 4 x_n < 0$ if $x_n > 8$. Moreover, $x_{n+1} > \frac 3 4 8 + 2 = 6 + 2 = 8$, so $x_1 = 12 > 8 \implies x_n > 8 \forall n \in \Bbb N$. Now it's obvious that a strictly decreasing, lower bounded sequence must converge.

The magical $8$ comes from the fact that $\{x_n\} \rightarrow 8$, which you can compute taking the fixed point in the recursion equation $L = \frac 3 4 L + 2 \iff L = 8$.

If you don't feel comfortable handling decreasing sequences (for whatever reason) you can just take $y_n = -x_n$, which is an increasing sequence. Just remember to go backwards at the end.